# How to dynamically add remove block using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing a problem while removing a paragraph, which I have added using javascript.
Adding buttons work fine. The problem occurs when I try to remove the paragraph.

```js
function rdn_id(){return Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);}

//create button
function create_btn()
{
   //Create a remove button
   var btn_remove = document.createElement("BUTTON");
   //create a unique button ID
   id_btn_remove = rdn_id();
   btn_remove.id = id_btn_remove ; 
   btn_remove.textContent = "Remove file";
   return [btn_remove, id_btn_remove];
}

//add elt function
function create_p_btn()
{
   //Create paragraph
   var paragraph = document.createElement("P");
   //create a unique p ID
   id_paragraph = rdn_id();
   paragraph.id = id_paragraph;
   paragraph.style.paddingTop = "5px";
   paragraph.style.background = "blue";
   document.getElementById("setItHere").appendChild(paragraph);

   // add button
   var values = create_btn();
   var btn_rmv = values[0];
   var id_btn = values[1];
   paragraph.appendChild(btn_rmv);
   document.getElementById(id_btn).addEventListener("onclick", function(){remove_func(id_paragraph);}); 
}

//Remove function
function remove_func(id_el)
{
    var elt = document.getElementById(id_el);
    elt.parentNode.removeChild(id_el);
}
```

```html
<div id="setItHere">
<Button id="start" onclick="create_p_btn();">add</Button>
</div>
```

Am I missing something ? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: try `if (removeFn) { remove_func = null } else { remove_func = copiedFn }`

Comment: Hey Rajesh, where should I add it ?

Comment: try https://jsfiddle.net/wq9yjkLv/

Comment: Hey @ghaziksibi it woks fine, thanks. What have you modified ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make two changes:

1. Event name should be `click` instead of `onclick`
2. `elt.parentNode.removeChild(id_el);` should be `elt.parentNode.removeChild(elt);`

Check out this pen
https://codepen.io/tanmayv/pen/yLNwNNJ

Comment: No problem @Kvin